# Adding menu via database in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I’m creating a php script which imports data from Joomla database to WordPress database, everything is being imported successfully (even menus) but when I add a new menu item the whole menu structure is destroyed and the parent & child relation/structure is lost.

Comment: Can You provide the code? Cause its to hard directly put into DB for reasons: 1. Menu by itself is a taxonomy in WP. It means that you can find all menus in `wp_terms` table 2. Menu item is custom post type in WP. They are stored in `wp_posts` table. 3. Relations between menus and menu items are stored in `wp_term_relationships` table. 4. Information about currently select menu is located in `wp_options` table as serialized PHP array. Much easy use ready WordPress tools and hooks for insert.

Comment: Since the file is too long I have uploaded it at my server and can be accessed via [link](https://www.gegabyte.org/subdomains/temp_upload/code.txt).

Few function in the file that have been used like PRINTR, PrintQ are simple function to show the result in formatted form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into it step by step I found the cause of the error. The error was being caused in the table "wp_postmeta" field "_menu_item_menu_item_parent" those item which were parent item were using value of "14" instead of "0".

"_menu_item_menu_item_parent" was using "14" due to the script because "14" is the id of the WordPress post that has been marked as "Default" in "Joomla".

Setting "0" value for "_menu_item_menu_item_parent" fixed the issue.